# Rails displaying a form based on user input

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a monthly report that calls for the user to enter a month then display the report for that month. I have the following to get the month:

```
= simple_form_for @month, html: { :class => 'form-inline' } do |f|
= f.input :month, label: 'Report Month', collection: month_select, input_html: {class: 'span2'}
```

I simply set up month as @month = ' '

Month is not in my database but I do have the filter coded to filter the database by month bassed on a date field. I just want the user to be able to select the month and see the results. Now the selection does not persist in the @month variable. I think I either need to implement a method in my controller to resubmit my form filtered on the month or else use javascript . I don't know how to do either

How do I set up a form to allow the entry of a date and then display the report for that date?

Comment: simple-form generally requires an ActiveModel object to be present. Do you know what that is? Alternatively, would you want a non-simple-form solution?

Comment: Non simple form is fine All I want to do is select a month, assign the month to a variable and display a report filtered on that month - I want the selection and report on the same page preferably - so the user can select march and see the total for March or whatever

Answer (score 1):

ok, so let's assume that you are listing our results for an Invoice model --- and you want to filter by month.

```
= form_tag url: invoices_path do
  = select_tag :month, month_select, prompt: true
  = submit_tag "Filter"
```

Then in your invoices_controller.rb:

```
def index
  @invoices = Invoice.by_month(params[:month])
end
```

and in your invoice.rb model:

```
def self.by_month(selected_month=nil)
  if month
    where(month: selected_month)
  else
    scoped
  end
end
```